# variable getter functions in golang

Tags: arrays, go, stack

Consider the following stack implementation in go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

var a [10]int
var top int = -1

func main() {
    printStack()
    push(1)
    printStack()
    push(23)
    printStack()
    pop()
    push(2)
    printStack()
    println("Top element is", getTop)
}

func push(x int) {
    top += 1
    a[top] = x
}

func pop() {
    top -= 1
}

func getTop() int {
    return a[top]
}

func printStack() {
    fmt.Println(top+1, "Stack: ", a, "Top", getTop)
}
```

Questions:

1. When I use `println("Top element is", getTop)`, it prints out memory address `0x193928` but when I call `println("Top element is", getTop())`, it returns `2`. Returning 2 makes sense but I don't understand why its returning memory address? shouldn't call getTop without brackets be invalid?
2. It seems that you can't have variable & functions with same name in golang. is that correct assumption to make?

Play: https://play.golang.org/p/vvOGG296gr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can pass your function as a var, for example: https://play.golang.org/p/wzGVtsEFQk . So `getTop` is a "function pointer", which explains the address being printed
2. Explained by #1: if it is declared in the same scope, your var name and function name collide